# SSIS Package Writes 0 rows but run DataFlow only and get 400k rows

Tags: sql, join, ssis, sql-server-2014, dataflow

I use my own login. I had to add a new join to OLEDB source query and tested with execute of Dataflow task and works 400k rows. Then run within package return is 0 rows and no error or warning

Comment: Probably need to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/configure-a-user-to-create-and-manage-sql-server-agent-jobs

Comment: yes I deploy to a server that uses an agent but because I use my login in test and get 2 different results I don't see a login or permission issue there may be something else regarding the join

Comment: it works independently under table and fast load but when it runs as part of the package that fills other tables in the group it just skips right over returning 0 rows like it doesn't even try- no warning in the log either

Comment: I take the join out  and it runs with the package

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: select bunch of columns from 
 RMA_Stage
INNER JOIN  RMA_Status
 ON RMA_Stage.RMA_Status_Key = RMA_Status.RMA_Status_Key 
INNER JOIN RMA_Type
 ON RMA_Stage.RMA_Type_Key = RMA_Type.RMA_Type_Key
--INNER JOIN Support_RMA_SuperType st
 --ON RMA_Type.RMA_Type_Natural_Key = st.SVC_Return_Type
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product
 ON Product.Part_Number = RMA_Stage.Part_Number_Orig

Comment: What does "run within package" mean? are you saying you deployed the package and ran it? from the catalog or from a SQL Agent job?

Comment: @Nick SSIS package has many Data Flow Tasks and Exec SQL Tasks. I successfully tested my joined query in SQL 2008, 2014, 2016. But does not work in SSIS 2014 in Test or deployed to 2016 Catalog or run by agent   Can I have a thumbs up ? fixing this by removing the join worked for me

Comment: Surely removing a join makes it do something different to what it's mean to do

Comment: Yes the join in my case set a column value and removing the join meant I had to add the column later with an update executable after the data load this is a good work around again can I have a thumbs up?

Answer (score -1):

SSIS gets confused with too many joins. If the joins are just replacing values with lookups then move one or more to a sql task and use an update statement after the load